# API gives back an array but data not showing on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, rendering

I'm trying to show some tickets on the screen from an APi. I did the petition with a fetch and the console is showing me an array with the data that I want to be shown on screen.

Everything seems to be okay but the tickets ain't in the screen.
[here is the array showing on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQl1I.png)

```
render() {
return (
  <article>
    <section className="container">
      {this.state.tickets.map((ticket) => (
        <div onClick={this.onclicked} key={ticket.id}>
          {this.state.clicked === true && (
            <div className="boxinfo">
              <h1 className="info">{ticket.fecha_adquisicion}</h1>
              <h2 className="info">{ticket.id_comercio}</h2>
              <h3 className="info">{ticket.precio_total}</h3>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </section>
  </article>
);
  }
```

That's the render method I did. I was thinking about the undefined " REACT_APP_SERVER_URL: " the console is showing from my api, it could may be the function I did on the API isn't right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.

What is happening here that you are not returning something from the `.map()` function

it should be fixed by doing this

```js
render() {
return (
  <article>
    <section className="container">
      {this.state.tickets.map((ticket) => {
        return <div onClick={this.onclicked} key={ticket.id}>
          {/* your code*/}
        </div>
      )}}
    </section>
  </article>
);
  }
```

Comment: It's not working, I mean where is the change this is literally same code but without the info. I don't get it sorry

Comment: I added the return to .map